# The new Input System doesn't trigger anything anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*This post is shamelessly a copy/paste from my post on the Unity Forums : https://forum.unity.com/threads/input-system-doesnt-trigger-anything-anymore.717386/, but Stack Overflow seems more active*

*TL;DR : InputSystem worked some days ago, don't trigger anything anymore, halp.*

I tried the new Input System some days ago, and that's really neat ! I did a lot of stuff, trying to understand the best way to use it, and, in the end, I had a character jumping and moving everywhere, that was cool ! Then, I merged my code in our develop branch and went to bed.

Today, I want to continue my code, but my character doesn't move anymore, Actions are not triggered (even if inputs are detected in debugger) and I really don't know why. Either the code merge overwrote some important settings (I know what you're thinking and yes, the "Active Input Handling" is set on "Both" and I tried only running the preview) or I did something important during my little tests and I didn't realize.

So I decided to try to reproduce my steps on a fresh new project, maybe you guys can help me figure what do I do wrong ?

1/ Create a new 2D project (via the Hub)

2/ Install the latest Package (version 0.9.0)

3/ Click Yes on that message prompt to activate the new Input management in the settings
[image: Prompt]

4/ Restart Unity Editor since it didn't restart even if the message said it would and check the project settings (yes, it's on "Both", and yes, my Scripting Runtime Version is 4.0)
[image: Settings]

5/ Create a new GameObject and add a PlayerInput on it

6/ Click on "Open Input Settings" and create an "InputSettings" asset

7/ Click on "Create Actions..." to create my ActionMap asset

8/ Create a "TestAction" on my "Player" ActionMap and set it to the key "t"

[image: [ATTACH=full]457769[/ATTACH]]

9/ Create a new Script "TestScript" that contains a OnTestAction() method (that only logs "test") and enables the test map/action (just to be sure) :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        InputActionMap playerActionMap = GetComponent<PlayerInput>().actions.GetActionMap("Player");
        playerActionMap.Enable();
        playerActionMap.GetAction("TestAction").Enable(); //Just to be sure
    }

    public void OnTestAction()
    {
        Debug.Log("test");
    }
}
```

10/ Pressing "Play" and spamming "T" like a madman to try to display a debug (note that, in the debugger, a User is created, my "t" presses are detected, my TestAction exists and is mapped on the "t" key but no debug is displayed
[image: Debug]

It's probably a silly problem, but it's driving me crazy, what do I do wrong ? It's even more infuriating that it worked some days ago !

Additional information :
- Switching the Input Management from "Both" to "New Input System (preview) does nothing
- Checking in Update() is my action is enabled returns "True" every frame
- Checking in Update() is my action is triggered returns "False" every frame
- Using action.started/triggered/performed does nothing (I tried also switching to UnityEvent or C# events for this) :

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputAction a;

    void Start()
    {
        InputActionMap playerActionMap = GetComponent<PlayerInput>().actions.GetActionMap("Player");
        playerActionMap.Enable();
        a = playerActionMap.GetAction("TestAction");
        a.Enable(); //Just to be sure
        a.started += OnTriggeredTestAction;
        a.performed += OnTriggeredTestAction;
        a.canceled += OnTriggeredTestAction;
    }

    public void OnTestAction()
    {
        Debug.Log("test");
    }

    public void OnTriggeredTestAction(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {
        Debug.Log("test triggered");
    }
}
```

- Injecting directly the InputActionReference of my TestAction and using it does nothing
- Forcing "Default Control Scheme" and "Default Action Map" does nothing
- Using BroadcastMessage or UnityEvents doesn't work

Comment: I solved this by restarting the computer : it seems that the input system is based on how long your computer have been on, so a restart solved it. Notice the negative time in the debugger that is not supposed to be like this.

Comment: OMG... are you sure that was the problem? If that's true... that is scary.

Answer (score 6):

You probably tried to import a new input system package for multiple input devices compatibility. These types of errors are due to conflict between old and new input system packages and are probably resolved in the latest updates.

To resolve this issue, Go to **Edit** -> **Project Settings**->**Player**->Under **Other Settings** under **Configuration** is the option **Active Input Handling**. Select **[Both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t2nT.png)**. Unity will restart. Now your problem should be solved. You will be able to use old input system packages and the new ones also simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

Posting just incase others run into this issue, as this solved my problem. Make sure to call Enable() for it to start routing events.

```
//Create a and set the reference
private InputControls _inputMapping;
private void Awake() => _inputMapping = new InputControls();

//Route and Un-route events
private void OnEnable() => _inputMapping.Enable();
private void OnDisable() => _inputMapping.Disable();
```

Answer (score 4):

Check for rogue *users* in the input debugger

I was having very similar symptoms (Input System would randomly just stop sending callbacks). When I opened up the input debugger, it was registering the key presses, but the callbacks were never being called in my script.

Restarting Unity didn't help.
Rebooting didn't help.

I also discovered in the input debugger that there were 2 "users" in the input system and (by process of disabling Game Objects in the scene one at a time) discovered that I had accidentally attached another copy of my Input Action Asset to a different Game Object in the scene and that Unity was registering this other object as a 2nd player or "user", which was assigned all the input action bindings I was trying to capture.

The rogue Action Asset was essentially intercepting the actions, preventing the callbacks from being called on the intended script. I don't know if that's your particular issue, but maybe it will help someone else who (like me) has spent hours pouring through forums, looking for a solution to this elusive problem.

An easy way to tell if you have the same problem is to open the input debugger and see if the desired actions are actually mapped to the user of interest.

Screen clip of input debugger:

[image: screen clip of input debugger here]

For me, there was an unexpected User #1 and only one of the users (not the intended one) actually had keys bound to the desired actions

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, reproduced with exactly the steps described in the question.
In my case, I forgot to set **control schemes**.

The problem was fixed after adding them.

To do so:

1. Open your **Input Action Asset**.
2. Select a control scheme, in the upper left corner. (say, Keyboard) (if you haven't added a control scheme to begin with, your problem may be different than mine)
3. Go **Right Click > Edit Control Scheme**.
   [EditControlScehme Screen Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGp1F.png)
4. Click on the plus sign to add a control scheme to the list.
   [Add control scheme to the list Screen Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEETh.png)
5. Select the control scheme you want to add. (in this case, Keyboard)
   [Select control scheme Screen Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEVxE.png)
6. Should look like this:
   [Added control scheme Screen Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrCqd.png)
7. You're all set. Save everything and the problem should be fixed.
8. Play your game and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for you but it worked for me and I was having the same issue.

I had created 2 control schemes. Mobile and Pc. Mobile required touch screen and PC required keyboard and Mouse. Doing this made my Mobile input event stop firing. So adding the Gamepad to my Mobile Control scheme allowed the events to fire again.

TLDR. Check your control scheme make sure it allows for the inputs your binding to.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case it was *ProjectSettings → Editor → EnterPlayModeOptions* which should have `Reload Domain` enabled. It seems like Input System has some static state, which should be cleared before new play. That is why restarting unity helps in this case.

IMHO it should force domain reload if it need one.

So the temporal solution is to enable `Domain Reload` when you want to change your `InputActionAsset` and disable it back when you done, because this feature enabled saves lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

As of at least Unity 2020.1.2 and Input System 1.0.0 the input system will randomly stop working correctly. The only fix I'm aware of is [restarting Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/input-system-doesnt-trigger-anything-anymore.717386/).